# LibreOffice 5.1 looks weird

Tags: user-interface, libreoffice

After installing the LibreOffice 5.1 update there's a weird visual glitch with toolbars. 
Can I do anything about it? 
Thank you! 
[image]

UPD: the problem is that there are these strange-looking white lines above toolbars.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see the error in your screenshot. Mind explaining your problem a bit?

Comment: @r3bl I think the OP means the white bar above each toolbar

Comment: You can try "sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk3"

Comment: wow, yours actually look better than mine - my install of LO 5.1 looks like something from windows 98 :(

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice are moving from Gtk2 to Gtk3, it's not complete yet and buggy. And the toolbar does not use the correct css class that's why.

The same issue in other distros/themes.
[image]
Screenshot using the latest version of Libreoffice, Gtk 3.20, Arc theme and Arch as distro.